# How to change background of a selected cardview in recyclerview adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to change the background of cardview if user selects it and want to change background of only one cardview at a time.

Like if user select any other cardview the background of previous selected cardview should come to original color.

**RecyclerviewAdapter code so far.**

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final List_data1 ld = list_data.get(position);
    holder.servicetype.setText(ld.getTitle());

    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            isselected = true;

            if (isselected == true) {
                holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent("custom-message");
            intent.putExtra("servicename", ld.getTitle());
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(v.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list_data.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CardView cardView;
    private TextView servicetype;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        servicetype = itemView.findViewById(R.id.servicetype);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare mClickedItem variable at a class level like -

```
private int mClickedItem = -1;
```

and do the handling on onBindViewHolder()

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (mClickedItem != -1) {
            if (mClickedItem == position) {
                holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


         if(mClickedItem != -1) {
                  notifyItemChanged(mClickedItem);
             }
                mClickedItem = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                notifyItemChanged(mClickedItem);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Since you are maintaining a single selection so this is the best solution instead of resetting and notifying the complete list.

Comment: The color of previous selected cardview is not getting back to original

Comment: Have added the code to notify last position too like -  if(mClickedItem != -1) {
                      notifyItemChanged(mClickedItem);
                 }